# How do I pass current folder contents to docker image in CircleCI?

Tags: docker, circleci

I have a project repo which contains my project and a docker-compose.yml file.

In the docker-compose file it mounts the current it's in ($pwd) and then run a command.

I can't seem to find a way of making this work using Circle CI. When I run the docker-compose file it doesn't seem to be mounting the volume. How do I pass the current folder contents into the image in Circle CI?

This is my current config.yml file - https://github.com/mikebell/mikebell.io/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml

Answer (score 2):

When using the `docker` executor (which you are) the special step `setup_remote_docker` needs to be run within the job to enable access to a Docker Engine daemon. In this case, that still won't be enough because even then, mounting volumes won't work. You need to use the `machine` executor.

The `machine` executor on CircleCI will allow you to mount volumes via the Docker CLI or Docker Compose.

Reference - https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/docker-compose/#using-docker-compose-with-machine-executor